# How can network switch recognize the connected device is on?

Tags: switch

I was just using a unmanaged switch and IoT devices,
and I noticed that the LINK/ACT LED turned on and blink during the boot sequence of device.

Then I wondered how network switch recognized this device were booting while plugged
because it was on U-boot without using ethernet like dhcp, tftp.

I tested it with managed switch, but it just uses SSDP, ARP or something else,
and reacted much later than unmanaged one.

How does a network unmanaged switch recognize its port connection?
A RX packet or bytes? or anything else?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, unmanaged devices are off-topic here. There is not configuration for us to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port LED simply shows the link state of the port on the physical layer (L1). Ethernet uses an auto-negotiation sequence with *fast link pulses* to establish a link with the best mutual speed and duplex mode. There are periodic signals to keep the link up. Useful data carried in frames can only be transmitted when a link is "up".

What is actually running on that port doesn't concern the switch. It simply learns the present MAC address(es) and forwards frames based on those addresses on the data link layer (L2). Everything happening in the layers above (network layer (L3) to application layer (L7)) isn't visible for a simple switch.

A port on a managed switch may also go through a spanning-tree integration phase - the spanning-tree protocol initially blocks the port for a few seconds until it has been established that there's no loop (vastly simplified). You can often use vendor-specific options like `portfast` or `admin-edge-port` to speed up that process for edge ports leading to end nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but now I got more questions that  
1) Is auto-negotiation a HW or SW character? I guess it would be HW because I didn't allocated MAC or IP address on my bootloader but LINK LED was on.  
2) What happens if auto-negotiation fail? Default setting for each? What happens if the default setting those were different?  
3) What happens if switch thinks the link is up but device thinks not? I guess only switch sends management packets and disable link when absense of reply, but doesn't it have side-effects?  
Thank you so much!

Comment: AN is mostly done in hardware, depending on the device. If AN fails, most PHYs try to detect the rate of incoming symbols and the duplex mode falls back to half duplex (for 10 & 100 Mbit/s). Unilateral links are only possible without AN. There are no "management packets" for establishing and maintaining a link, just link pulses and IDLE symbols. You can learn all about Auto Negotiation in IEEE 802.3 Clause 28.

Comment: Note: the port LED has nothing to do with MAC addresses